# Could Not Set the Visible Property Error when Hiding a Frame

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm having an issue in Excel 2007 VBA whereby I'm trying to set the visible property to false on a frame within a UserForm.

```
Userform1.Frame1.Visible = False
```

When trying to set the property, excel throws the error:

> Run-time error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)':
>
> Could not set the Visible property. Unexpected call to method or property access.

I've researched this and the only thing that I've uncovered is that it *might* be something to do with not having a control to take the focus. In my case this is not true though as there is a button available to take the focus on another frame. The other frame is set to be visible prior to `Frame1` being hidden.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or can help me understand what is causing this error?

**Edit - Code Addition**

```
Public Sub fOpenFrame(uf As UserForm, strName As String)

Dim con As Control
Dim i As Long

i = 5

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With uf.Controls(strName)
    .Top = 38.15
    .Left = 120
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 565
    .Visible = True
End With

For Each con In uf.Controls
    If TypeName(con) = "Frame" And con.Name <> strName And InStr(con.Name, "Menu") < 1 _
    And con.Name <> "frmNewAbsenceButton" And con.Name <> "frmExistingAbsenceButton" Then
        With con
            .Visible = False 'Error occurs here'
            .Top = 5
            .Left = i
            .Height = 20
            .Width = 20
        End With
        i = i + 25
    End If
Next con

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Edit 2 - Pictures Added**

This is the first frame `Frame1`. A msgbox pops up and when the user clicks yes, it opens `Frame2`.
[image: Picture One]

This is `Frame2`. This frame opens with all the textboxes / comboboxes disabled. The button control 'Edit' is enabled.
[image: Picture Two]

Comment: Could you please add the previous two lines of code before setting the Form to Invisible? You might have to manually set the focus on to another object, as you cannot set the visibility an object to False when it currently has focus.

Comment: @PaulFrancis I've added the procedure that fires prior to the line that errors out. Essentially the procedure loops through the relevant frames and sets there visibility to false apart from the fame to be opened. Thanks

Comment: Try creating a "camouflaged" control, could even be a button, that will do nothing but change focuses. Then just before you set `con.Visible = False`, set the focus on the newly created control. This might be a work around. However the error is a bit bizarre, have you tried removing the `On Error Resume Next` and see where the actual error is?

Comment: @PaulFrancis Thanks for the suggestion. Re `On Error Resume Next`, that's only there as a placeholder so I can continue to develop with the issue there. Removing it produces the exact same error. I've just tried adding a blank button and setting the focus to it but the error is still thrown!

Comment: When you are calling `fOpenFrame` method?

Comment: It gets called after the caption of the form is changed. I can post the additional code?

Comment: @shA.t `frmNewAbsence`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean sorry?

Comment: Pardon Me, Add your data from comments to your question and reduce comments, plz. and In you `IF` => you check `con.Name <> "frmNewAbsenceButton"` Is it correct or checking `con.Name <> "frmNewAbsence"`

Comment: Thanks and yes `frmNewAbsenceButton` is correct.

Comment: Maybe you will find your answer here (http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1538366)

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of the Userform/Frames in question will help us pick up something not code related?

Comment: @PatricK I've uploaded pictures thanks.

Comment: Hi @Gareth, all the different sets of frames are on top of each other?

Comment: @PatricK Hi, no thy're not on top of each other. They're visibility is set to hidden and they're positioned to the top of the userform.

Comment: I think your problem is not in this module, is there anyway to have your vba files or all codes ?

Comment: @shA.t Unfortunatly I'm unable to post the complete files / code. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried to set ```Visible = false``` on all the controls which are inside of the frame in the first place? If this succeeds then try to set ```frame.Visible = false```.

Comment: @dee Thanks for the suggestion, I've just tried iterating through all of the controls in the frame with I was able to set as not visible. It still unfortunately failed when trying to make the frame invisible.

Comment: Ok and did you tried instead of ```Frame.Visible = False``` to set ```Frame.Height = 0``` and ```Frame.Width = 0```? This should make the frame "invisible" as well. If possible export the UserForm and upload it to some server (e.g. DropBox) ... this might help to reproduce the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to make all frames invisible first (and not to care about their position nor size); after that the only relevant frame can be made visible.
If the sub is in the userform's macromodule you can use Me("Frame4") and refrain from the argument: 'uf as userform'.

```
Public Sub fOpenFrame(uf As UserForm, strName As String)
 for each it in uf.controls
  if typename(it)="Frame" then it.visible=false
 next

 With uf.Controls(strName)
  .Top = 38.15
  .Left = 120
  .Height = 400
  .Width = 565
  .Visible = True
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but switching the procedure around doesn't make a difference. With regards to procedure itself, it's not within the UserForms code module.

Comment: So what if you place it in the userform's code  module ?

Comment: In can hardly believe you have several frames, dimensioned   .Top = 5
 .Height = 20, .Width = 20 and placed on the same line on postion 5,30,55,80,105 , etc. It doesn't match the pictures you posted.

Comment: That's because they're visibility is set to hidden as per the procedure posted so when running, the frames aren't visible.

Comment: In that case I would put all those frames into a 'container' frame. The only thing you have to do at runtime is making that container frame visible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that and will report back.

Comment: Rather than using frames and "visible", have you considered using a multi page control?  You simply put the different controls on different pages, set the page style to not show tab headers and then your control buttons simply change the active page, no need to set anything to visible or otherwise.  Its a technique I use often when creating wizards.  Not put as an answer as its a radical change to what you are asking for, so just something to consider.  But once done its a very useful technique

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue intermittently.

After reading the other answers, I added `.setfocus` call to a valid textbox before I the `visible = false` call, and it seemed to fix the issue.

```
With con
     textbox1.setfocus 'Adding this seemed to fix the issue
     .Visible = False 'Error occurs here'
     .Top = 5
     .Left = i
     .Height = 20
     .Width = 20
End With
```

Answer (score -3):

I have tested in excel 2010 the the code is working fine(I don't have excel 2007)

Please try the below code.

```
Private Sub Frame1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.Frame1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, it just uses the same method which the OP has already attempted (i.e., control `.Visible`).